# Enforcing background-color to text only

Tags: html, css, web

I would like to ask how can I give my text ONLY with the background-color property and not the spacing using CSS or HTML or both.

For example,

Hello everyone!

I only want the background-color to show on Hello and everyone! and not the entire length of Hello everyone!

I have tried searching in the Internet but I can't find any solution.

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't possible without wrapping each piece of text in its own element.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap each word in a span element and give the span elements background colours.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your text inside a wrapper, and style it with

```
display: inline;
background-color: whatever;
```

Note that if you use a wrapper which is inline by default (e.g. `<span>`), you don't need `display: inline`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of different ways to do this, but for a beginner I'd recommend wrapping all text with `<span>`.

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/kehlan/WLV6S/)